# How to upgrade iRobot create_2 firmware to 3.2.6

Tags: ros, create-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The create_autonomy github readme indicates that the Create 2 (firmware >= 3.2.6). Been googling and contacted iRobot twice, still unable to figure how to upgrade firmware to 3.2.6. Any help in this matter will be deeply appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262720/how-to-upgrade-irobot-create_2-firmware-to-3.2.6/) by [robert.zwemer](https://answers.ros.org/users/30540/robert.zwemer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've contacted iRobot in the past and at the time firmware version 3.2.6 was considered old, containing a few bugs. But the known bugs are not critical and should not affect the operation of create_autonomy. They were reluctant to help me upgrade the firmware unless it was absolutely necessary. I believe it may involve them sending you a proprietary USB device to facilitate the upgrade. Have you confirmed that your robot has firmware version lower than 3.2.6? Chances are it is of equivalent version or greater if you purchased the robot within the last two years.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2017-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robert.zwemer](https://answers.ros.org/users/30540/robert.zwemer/) on 2017-05-29**:
Thank you for the prompt reply. After some more googling, found references to a device called an OSMO, which apparently can be used to upgrade firmware. Have not found method to determine firmware version, would appreciate knowing how to do this, if you can help.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2017-05-29**:
I think you can use a serial communication tool (like [cutecom](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Cutecom)), open a connection with the robot, and send the reset signal (hex value 07). There should be some startup message with firmware verison if I remember correctly.

**Comment by [robert.zwemer](https://answers.ros.org/users/30540/robert.zwemer/) on 2017-05-29**:
Got it, thank you Here are the results:

2012-03-22-1549-L
r3_robot/tags/release-3.2.6:4975 CLEAN

bootloader id: 4714 624C 4F35 9FFF
assembly: 3.5-lite
revision: 0
flash version: 10
flash info crc passed: 1

Actually using Arduino Serial Monitor.

Thanx again, I'm retired 70 year old tinkerer.